# How do I remove specific uicontextmenu options in MATLAB (e.g. in the legend's menu)

Tags: matlab, contextmenu, matlab-figure

So, I have a legend (on a plot) in an application I'm working on. If you right click on it a bunch of optional actions come up. These include things like 'Interpreter', 'Location', 'Orientation', etc.. I know that one can overwrite this menu by setting your own uicontextmenu `set(axes,'uicontextmenu',newmenu)`, but how do you just edit it? What if I wanted to prevent a user from adjusting the legend's location but nothing else?

Is this kind of customisation possible?
Here's the code I've been testing/messing with this on.

```
x = 1:20;
y = cos(x);
z = sin(x);
plot(x,y);
hold on
plot(x,z);
lg = legend('stuff1','stuff2');
% remove the menu altogether
%set(lg,'uicontextmenu','')
```

I am running R2014b

EDIT: To be completely clear, I want to be able to remove some options from an existing uicontextmenu (that I did not create explicitly), but not all.

Comment: Have you tried setting a fixed position for the legend? I think that blocks further manual movement...

Comment: That was just an example, I'm not specifically looking to prevent legend location; I don't want the option to be available to the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing you'll need to do is set the [`ShowHiddenHandles` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.root-properties.html#buc8_0n-ShowHiddenHandles) of the [root object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/groot.html) to `'on'`, which will make hidden handles discoverable. Then you can just do the following:

```
>> hMenu = get(lg, 'UIContextMenu')  % Get the context menu handle

hMenu = 

  ContextMenu with properties:

    Callback: ''
    Children: [12×1 Menu]  % This would be empty if handles were still hidden

  Show all properties

>> hItems = get(hMenu, 'Children')  % Get the menu item handles

hItems = 

  12×1 Menu array:

  Menu    (scribe:legend:mcode)
  Menu    (scribe:legend:propedit)
  Menu    (scribe:legend:orientation)
  Menu    (scribe:legend:location)
  Menu    (scribe:legend:interpreter)
  Menu    (scribe:legend:font)
  Menu    (scribe:legend:linewidth)
  Menu    (scribe:legend:edgecolor)
  Menu    (scribe:legend:color)
  Menu    (scribe:legend:edittitle)
  Menu    (scribe:legend:delete)
  Menu    (scribe:legend:refresh)

>> delete(hItems(4));  % Delete the fourth item
```

The above could also be done with dot notation for property access like so:

```
delete(lg.UIContextMenu.Children(4));
```

In addition, you can leave the handles hidden and use [`findall`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findall.html), which requires you to know some of the properties of the object you're looking for. For example, to find and delete the menu object with the `'Label'` property set to `'Location'` in the current figure, do this:

```
delete(findall(gcf, 'Label', 'Location'));
```

And for all of the above you can confirm that the "Location" option is now gone from the context menu:

[image]

Comment: That hidden handles trick is neat, don't know how I've never seen it before. Any other immediately useful applications for it?

Comment: @Wolfie: You don't actually have to mess with `ShowHiddenHandles` if you use `findall` instead of `findobj` (`findall` ignores hidden status). I build my GUIs with handle visibility set to hidden just to make it less likely for the user to break them.